# Java parse previous element in arraylist

Tags: java, parsing, arraylist

My goal: to parse all data in my CSV file to arraylist

Problem: there's a row with all "null" value, but I set to program to parse doubles, so, there's a **NumberFormatException**

What I tried: I intended to solve this problem by catching NumberFormatException and replace the null with previous day prices, but it doesn't work.

My question:
(1) how to set it to parse the previous element in arraylist in the code below?
(2) do I need to change the whole structure of the code to label every element in the array list so that I can set the null to the previous element specifically?

Thanks.

```
//import file, file path
        Scanner inputFile = checkFile("C:\\data\\3988.HK.csv");

        //Build up ArrayList to store data from file
        ArrayList<Date>Date = new ArrayList<Date>();
        ArrayList<Double>Open = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double>High = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double>Low = new ArrayList<Double>();
        ArrayList<Double>Close = new ArrayList<Double>();

        // Read the first line
        String line = inputFile.nextLine();

        // Add data to the 1st arraylists from the file
        while(inputFile.hasNext())
        {
            String[] data = inputFile.nextLine().split(",");
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            try 
            {
                Date.add(sdf.parse(data[0]));
            }
            catch(ParseException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Invalid format in the file.");
            }
            try
            {
                Open.add(Double.parseDouble(data[1])); 
                High.add(Double.parseDouble(data[2]));
                Low.add(Double.parseDouble(data[3]));
                Close.add(Double.parseDouble(data[4]));
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e)
            {
                System.out.print("Non-numeric data found in the file.\nThe invalid record will be replaced the previous day prices.");
                Open.add(Open.previous()); 
                High.add(High.previous());
                Low.add(Low.previous());
                Close.add(Close.previous());
            }
        }
```

Comment: you can add a `if.. else` statement to check whether the value is `null` or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**One thing is your condition will be failed for very first row, as for first row there is no previous**

**Second thing is practically you should put 0 if value is null, not previous**

**Solution is you need to check row position and then use previous and also you need to define try catch in separate function and then call it as this will fail for one value and it will affect all 4 values.**

**Try below code**

```
        try 
        {
            Date.add(sdf.parse(data[0]));
        }
        catch(ParseException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid format in the file.");
        }
            Open.add(getLongFromData(data[1]));             
            High.add(getLongFromData(data[2]));
            Low.add(getLongFromData(data[3]));    
            Close.add(getLongFromData(data[4]));
```

**Create One Function for Value**

```
private long getLongFromData(String data)
{
        long longValue = 0;
        try
        {
            longValue = Double.parseDouble(data);
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e)
        {              
            longValue = 0;
        }
        return longValue;
}
```